# best way for query full text search using table filter

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

we want restrict query string using filter_table.

input query example :

```
best 2018 my_brand shoes
```

filter table :

words did not have white space.

```
-------
filter_table
-------
brand <- query has this word so return true
my_brand<- query has it but we did not consider it.
your_brand
....
last_brand
-------
```

return :

```
if input query have sub_word in filter table, return true else return false.
```

Brute force method will be very slow, Is there any best structure for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using elastic search with ngram analyzer.
Ngram analyzer return is very faster than SQL.